# Simulating mouse move in Math Input Panel (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, winapi, math, windows-7, mouseevent

I would like to compare my application for handwritten mathematical symbols recognition with the Math Input Panel (MIP) contained in Windows 7. I have a library of recorded mouse strokes representing different mathematical formulas and I need to send them to the MIP to measure its performance.

I tried to simulate mouse move but it's not working.

Here are constants and imported methods that I use:

```
const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
const UInt32 MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dx, UInt32 dy, UInt32 dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

And that's the code itself:

```
IntPtr windowHandle = FindWindow("MathInput_Window", "");
SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);

Cursor.Position = new Point(600, 700);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 600, 700, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);

for (int x = 600; x <= 650; x++)
{
    Cursor.Position = new Point(x, 700);
}

for (int y = 700; y <= 750; y++)
{
    Cursor.Position = new Point(650, y);
}

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 650, 750, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
```

But the only thing i get is a single dot at the position [600,700]. The funny thing is that when I use MSPaint instead of MIP everything is working perfectly.

Does anyone have some idea how it could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I have already solved the problem using the following function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);
```

I call it to control both mouse button clicks and mouse moves and it works perfectly.